# Multiple fullscreen android notifications at the same time not stacking

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, android-pendingintent

I am working on an android project that has an alarm clock like functionality.

I schedule an intentService for each alarm instance (fires at 9pm, for example.), this intentService builds the notification and displays it. The notification includes a fullScreenIntent, which works as expected and launches the activity. I use the following code to do this:

```
alarmActivityIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmActivity.class);
PendingIntent alarmActivityPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, alertSchedule.getIntentId(), alarmActivityIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
mBuilder.setFullScreenIntent(alarmActivityPendingIntent, true);
Notification mNotification = mBuilder.build();
mNotificationManager.notify(alertSchedule.getIntentId(), mNotification);
```

This works as expected when only one alarm is set to fire at a specific time, however if two alarms are set to fire at a specific time the behavior changes.

I want the first fullScreenIntent to start its activity, then when that activity finishes, show the next one. I believe I want to build up a task stack, and push these alarm intents onto it. However this is all new to me.

Is it possible to group these notifications?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the full screen `Intent` feature, you don't need to use an `IntentService` or a `Notification` at all. Just have the `AlarmManager` start your `Activity` when it fires.

You don't want to build a task stack, that is all too complicated. If you have multiple alarms that can fire at the same time, you can have the `AlarmManager` start the same `Activity` each time. Set the launch mode of this `Activity` to `singleTop` (in the manifest), so that if the `Activity` is already showing when the alarm fires, it will not create another instance of the `Activity` on top of the existing one, but instead will deliver the `Intent` by calling `onNewIntent()` on the existing instance of the `Activity`. In `onNewIntent()` you can save the data (extras) of the `Intent` in a queue that will be processed when the user finishes the currently shown `Activity`. To do that, just override `onBackPressed()` so that when the user presses the BACK button to finish the current `Activity`, you can check if there are any additional alarms waiting in the queue. If there are none, you can just call `super.onBackPressed()` to finish the `Activity`. If there is anything in the queue, you can remove the first element in the queue and display that in your `Activity`. Keep doing that until the queue is empty.

Comment: Hey David, thanks for the response. The reason for the intent service is that using the full screen intent is a user optional feature. Would this be the correct way to implement it? I still want them to get the notification, just not  the screen wake.

Comment: You can still use the `Notification` if you want to, but the solution should work in either case. `Notification` should launch `Activity` which should queue alarm if there is already an alarm on screen.